# Why does `puts(nil or 4)` fail in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

When I do:

```
puts(nil or 4)
```

Ruby complains:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error, unexpected keyword_or, expecting ')'
```

Why is that? `puts(nil || 4)` does work, but I wonder why `or` doesn't. I thought the difference between the two was only in their operator precedence.

(I know the expression `nil or 4` doesn't seem useful, as it always returns `4`. It's just an example, for simplicity's sake. My actual expression is `Integer(ENV['WD'] or 4)`.)

Comment: Oddly enough, `puts (nil or 4)` works fine - a space has been put after `put`

Comment: It seems like a bug)

Comment: If it's a bug, `and` has the same bug.

Comment: `puts((nil or 4))` also works!?!

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth: see my answer :)

Answer (score 15):

#### Short answer

Because that's how ruby syntax is.

#### Longer answer

`and`/`or` keywords were designed to be used in control flow constructs. Consider this example:

```
def die(msg)
  puts "Exited with: #{msg}"
end

def do_something_with(arg)
  puts arg
end

do_something_with 'foo' or die 'unknown error'
# >> foo
# >> Exited with: unknown error
```

Here `or` works nicely with ruby's optional parentheses, because of ruby [parsing rules (pseudo-BNF)](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/yacc.html).

In short, an argument list (CALL_ARGS) is a list of ARG, separated by comma. Now, most anything is an ARG (class definitions, for example, through being a PRIMARY), but not an unadorned EXPR. If you surround an expression with parentheses, then it'll match a rule for "compound statement" and, therefore, will be a PRIMARY, which is an ARG. What this means is that

```
puts( (nil or 4) ) # will work, compound statement as first argument
puts (nil or 4)  # same as above, omitted optional method call parentheses
puts(nil or 4) # will not work, EXPR can't be an argument
puts nil or 4 # will work as `puts(nil) or 4`
```

You can read the grammar referenced above to understand *exactly* how it works.

#### BONUS: Example of class definition being a valid ARG

```
puts class Foo
       def bar
         puts "hello"
       end
     end, 'second argument'

# >> bar # this is the "value" of the class definition
# >> second argument
```

Comment: great explanation!

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth: because they can be ARG. https://monosnap.com/file/wEA1jUDcU4CQ81Fuh7hkEcMgIf9K80.png.

Comment: Ah, I see. `and` and `or` have the precedence they do because they're not explicitly defined to be ARG. So many operators are definited to be ARG that it's easy to think that ARG and EXPR are the same. Nasty. I think we'd have been better off without `and` and `or`.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth: yes, exactly. I never use them. :)

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth And the style guide recommends against them. https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-and-or-or

Comment: I never use them either, simply because remembering details of operator precedence is annoying, but now I have a new reason to dislike them: their existence requires Ruby to have significantly more complicated parsing rules than it would without them. Or can they share the blame: is there other syntax that breaks the illusion that a method argument is a full-fledged expression?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev: thank you for the nice answer. I embarked on writing my own answer because the first version(s) of you answer left room for confusion, and I also wanted to know how exactly the BNF itself explains the `func (1 or 2)` thing.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: Thanks for linking to the style guide. But the anchor in the link doesn't work. Could you please write here 3 or 4 words that we should search for in that long document to arrive at the relevant section?

Comment: @NiccoloM.: the anchor does work for me. The guide is long, give it a second to load. :) And thanks for the good self-answer!

Comment: As for the style guide @SteveTurczyn linked to: for the benefit of users whose browsers aren't compatible with github's JavaScript anchors (I'm using a "old" Opera browser): you can search that long page for the sentence "The  and  and  or  keywords are banned" to arrive at the relevant section.

Comment: @NiccoloM. thanks for providing the search terms for anchor-incompatible browsers.

Answer (score 11):

It is because `or` and `and` have lower precedence than method call. Your expression is interpreted as:

```
{puts(nil} or {4)}
```

where `{}` stands for grouping. The syntax error comes from the expression

```
puts(nil
```

(and the following will also raise a syntax error):

```
4)
```

If you force grouping by putting a pair of parentheses around the expression, then it will work the way you intended:

```
puts((nil or 4))
```

Notice that the outer pair of parentheses is used for method call, not grouping, hence just having one pair of parentheses has no effect of changing the grouping.

Alternatively, if you disambiguate a single pair of parentheses to be used for grouping by putting a space, then that will work too:

```
puts (nil or 4)
```

Answer (score 7):

@Sergio Tulentsev (and @sawa) gave a good answer, but I want to rephrase it so I can understand it quickly in the future:

Ruby lets us drop parenthesis in function calls. That is, instead of:

```
func1(ARG, ARG, ARG) or func2(ARG, ARG, ARG)
```

We can do:

```
func1 ARG, ARG, ARG or func2 ARG, ARG, ARG
```

However, in order to make this last line behave like the first one, "or" can't be an operator used in the top-level of an ARG (otherwise that last line will be interpreted as `func1(ARG, ARG, ARG or func2 ARG, ARG, ARG)`). Indeed, when we look in the [BNF](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/yacc.html) we see that ARG doesn't directly mention "or"/"and" (which means it's illegal there).

But ARG still makes it possible to use "or": by wrapping the expression in parentheses. In the [BNF](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/yacc.html) we see this as the PRIMARY alternative that ARG can branch to (as PRIMARY, in its turn, branches to `'(' COMPSTMT ')'`).

#### Now, as to why `func (1 or 2)` and `func((1 or 2))` work whereas `func(1 or 2)` doesn't:

- `func(1 or 2)` is what the BNF calls FUNCTION, which expands to `OPERATION ['(' [CALL_ARGS] ')']`, which means the ARG is "1 or 2", but, as we've seen, ARG can't contain "or", so it's *invalid*.
- `func((1 or 2))` is, again, `OPERATION ['(' [CALL_ARGS] ')']`, but here the the ARG is "(1 or 2)", which is a *valid* ARG (see PRIMARY mentioned above).
- `func (1 or 2)` is what the BNF calls COMMAND, which expands to `OPERATION CALL_ARGS`, which means the ARG is "(1 or 2)", which is a *valid* ARG (see PRIMARY mentioned above).

Comment: Nice summarisation of the other answers with additional reasoning