# Why is it okay to write or but not ||?

Tags: ruby, operators

I understand there is a difference in the precedence as shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2083118/2909897):

```
p foo = false || true
# => true

p foo = false or true
# => false
```

But it seems like there is something more that's different between `or` and `||`.

For example:

```
p foo = 42 or raise "Something went wrong with foo"
# => 42
p foo = nil or raise "Something went wrong with foo"
# => Something went wrong with foo (RuntimeError)
p foo = 42 || raise "Something went wrong with foo"
# => syntax error, unexpected tOP_ASGN, expecting end-of-input
```

I was expecting to get:

```
p foo = 42 or raise "Something went wrong with foo"
# => 42
p foo = nil or raise "Something went wrong with foo"
# => Something went wrong with foo (RuntimeError)
p foo = 42 || raise "Something went wrong with foo"
# => Something went wrong with foo (RuntimeError)
```

But it's a syntax error. So what is happening?

Comment: Many Rubiests, myself included, *never* use `and` or `or`. Sticking with `&&` and `||` will simplify your life without limiting your options.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Theory :

Here's a [precedence table](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/doc/syntax/precedence_rdoc.html) for Ruby.

It's not clear from this table but Ruby method invocation without parentheses has a lower precedence than `||` and `=`, but higher than `or`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613287/why-does-putsnil-or-4-fail-in-ruby).

So for your code, from highest to lowest precedence :

- `||`
- `=`
- `raise "something"`
- `or`

## Expression with `or`

```
foo = 42 or raise "Something went wrong with foo"
```

First comes `=`  :

```
( foo = 42 ) or raise "Something went wrong with foo"
```

Then `raise` :

```
( foo = 42 ) or ( raise "Something went wrong with foo" )
```

Then `or` :

```
( ( foo = 42 ) or ( raise "Something went wrong with foo" ) )
```

## Expression with `||`

```
foo = 42 || raise "Something went wrong with foo"
```

First comes `||` :

```
foo = ( 42 || raise ) "Something went wrong with foo"
```

Here's your syntax error!

You want :

```
foo = 42 || (raise "Something went wrong with foo") #=> 42
```

or

```
foo = 42 || raise("Something went wrong with foo")  #=> 42
```

or just

```
foo = 42 || raise
```

## Warning!

When you have troubles with precedence, you should be careful about adding another `puts` or `p` without parentheses !

For example :

```
p [1,2,3].map do |i|
  i*2
end
```

outputs :

```
#<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:map>
```

even though you might have expected :

```
[2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Updated. Sorry, my first answer was wrong. `raise "something"` has higher precedence than `or`, even though I cannot find any official statement about it.

Comment: That's because `raise` is a method call. It is one of the global functions defined on the `Kernel` module and hence has the same syntax and precedence as any method call.

Answer (score 1):

`||` and `or` are not the same operation.

The first is equivalent to a method call, the latter is a control flow keyword. You probably always want to use `||` to avoid confusion with precedence. Most style guides for Ruby have a clause that bans the use of `and` and `or` for that reason.

So then,

```
A or B

# can be considered equivalent to

if A then A else B end
```

whereas

```
A || B

# can be considered equivalent to

A.or { B } # given a hypothetical "logical or" method
```

Now let's look into your `or` example

```
p foo = false or true
```

is equivalent to

```
temp = p(foo = false) # => nil
if temp
  temp
else
  true
end
```

and thus when executed prints `false` and returns `true`

```
[1] pry(main)> p foo = false or true
false
=> true
[2] pry(main)> foo
=> false
```

whereas

```
p foo = false || true
```

is equivalent to (glossing over the difference between boolean and logical OR for now since your example is dealing with booleans anyway)

```
p(foo = false.|(true))
```

and thus when executed prints `true` and returns `true`

```
[1] pry(main)> p foo = false || true
true
=> true
[2] pry(main)> foo
=> true
```

Comment: Same answer for 2 different questions, and you manage to miss the point on both! You don't explain the SyntaxError. `||` isn't equivalent to a method call because they don't have the same precedence at all, and `A || B` can also be seen as `if A then A else B end`.

Comment: You're right, they actually produce the same bytecode. Conceptually though one is meant to be a method-like operator while the other is meant for control flow. I can explain the syntax error … oh, and you do in your answer!